# How to change legend shape using geom_line and geom_point together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

My data:

> Date;original;fitted;phen;noise;type;type2;type3;type4
>
> 2013-04-16;0.77;0.76;NA;NA;1;2;3;4
>
> 2013-04-24;NA;0.73;NA;1;1;2;3;4
>
> 2013-05-10;NA;0.70;0.11;NA;1;2;3;4
>
> 2013-05-18;0.68;0.65;NA;1;1;2;3;4

I wanna plot original time-series X fitted time-series, showing some detected
points on the fitted time series and where there were noise. But I´m having troubles using the legend, once I want to show the proper legend for each representation.

I´m trying this:

```
ggplot(data=df) + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=fitted_data, color= >type2)) +  labs(x = "Dates", y="EVI") + 
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=original_data, color = type)) +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=phen, color = type3), size =3) +
geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=noise, color = type4), size =1.2) +
ylim(0, 1) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1, size=12)) >+ theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12)) +
theme(legend.text=element_text(size = 15), legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

But I want to show the right symbol for each representation

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(data=df) + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=fitted_data, color= type2)) +  labs(x = "Dates", y="EVI") + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=original_data, color = type)) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=phen, color = type3), size =3) +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=noise, color = type4), size =1.2) +
   ylim(0, 1) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30, hjust=1, size=12)) + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12)) +
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size = 10), legend.position="bottom")  +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black", "brown", "blue"),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                         linetype = c("blank", "solid", "blank", "blank"), shape = c(16, NA, 16, 16)
                         )))
```